# Calculating a tangent arc between two points on two circles

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, geometric-arc

How can I calculate the arc between two circles? The arc must be tangent to the two points on the circles.

Here is a picture illustrating it. I'm trying to code and calculate the orange arc and the blue arc.

[image]

more details:

Your applet should have 2 modes: 2D and 3D. The user should be able to switch between them by pressing the space bar. In the 2D mode, the user can edit the position of four control points A, B, C and D and should see 4 circular arcs defined by these points as follows. The red arc lies on a circle of center A and radius ||AB||. The green arc lies on a circle of center C and radius ||CD||. The orange arc lies on a supporting circle that is tangent to the supporting circle of the red arc at B and also tangent to the green circle at a point E, which your code must compute. This supporting circle should not separate A and C (i.e., A and C must either be both in that circle or out of it). Similarly, the blue arc lies on a circle that does not separate A and C and that is tangent to the supporting circle of the green arc at D and is also tangent to the supporting circle of the red arc at some point F which your program must compute. The red arc runs clockwise from F to B. The orange arc runs from B to E. The green arc runs from E to D. The blue arc runs from D back to F. These four arcs form a smooth boundary of a region S of the plane. Notice that depending on the position of the control points, the orange and blue arcs may each be either concave or convex. In the figure below, the blue arc is concave. (pictured above)

Comment: What information do you already have ?  Are the orange arc and the blue arc themselves parts of circles ?

Comment: This is straight math question. You should ask it here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are the radii of the blue and orange arcs specified as part of the problem? If they aren't then there are infinitely many possible arcs.

Comment: The user can click and drag points B, E, F, and D.

Comment: The radii is not specified, but changing. I don't think there is a specific arc that we need to calculate. My goal is to emulate the arcs in the given image.

Comment: If it is homework, please add the "homework" tag

Comment: @belisarius: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Comment: @Roger Pate Although I was not aware of the policy, I think adding the tag in this case is aligned with it. In my answer, there is a comment that clearly accepts this is homework. Besides, the poster asked another two questions about the same project, and none of them have the homework tag. I think homework questions are a great opportunity to enhance the learning process but also a great one to help cheating. The homework tag makes the difference. I'll not revert your edit, but please take a look at the other questions of the poster.

Comment: @belisarius: Homework questions are fine; the wording of the question here makes it fairly obvious, in fact.  Tagging for the intent of the poster rather than the content of the question is the issue here.  What you mention has been discussed before on the SO.meta question I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many "tangent circles" !

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to calculate either G or E?

Comment: @Russell yes, but it is boring analytical geometry.Moreover, this seems to be your homework ...

Comment: The homework is a lot more elaborate, this is just the first step, but I figured it out.

Comment: @Russell Great! If you already figured it out, please post it as an answer and accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can't. Draw straight lines through AB and CE, and extend them to the point of intersection. Call the intersection M. You can draw an arc through B and E that is tangent to circles if and only if BM = EM.

Comment: Your applet should have 2 modes: 2D and 3D. The user should be able to switch between them by pressing the space bar. In the 2D mode, the user can edit the position of four control points A, B, C and D and should see 4 circular arcs defined by these points as follows. The red arc lies on a circle of center A and radius ||AB||. The green arc lies on a circle of center C and radius ||CD||. The orange arc lies on a supporting circle that is tangent to the supporting circle of the red arc at B and also tangent to the green circle at a point E, which your code must compute.

Comment: This supporting circle should not separate A and C (i.e., A and C must either be both in that circle or out of it). Similarly, the blue arc lies on a circle that does not separate A and C and that is tangent to the supporting circle of the green arc at D and is also tangent to the supporting circle of the red arc at some point F which your program must compute. The red arc runs clockwise from F to B. The orange arc runs from B to E. The green arc runs from E to D. The blue arc runs from D back to F. These four arcs form a smooth boundary of a region S of the plane.

Comment: Notice that depending on the position of the control points, the orange and blue arcs may each be either concave or convex. In the figure below, the blue arc is concave. (pictured above)

Comment: Okay, so your 2D problem reduces to finding centers of the orange and the blue arcs, given A,B,C, and D. For the orange arc, the center (again, call it M) will lie on the line AB and it will satisfy the equality: |MB| = |MA| + |AB| = |MC| + |CD|. Can you figure out how to calculate its position from this equality?

Answer (score 0):

Let G be the center of the circle for the arc between B and E and H the circle for the arc between F and D.

The key point is that a line that intersects a circle is a tangent line if and only if it is perpendicular to the radius at the intersection point. This means that if you have two circles that are tangent, then the tangent point and the centers of the circles are collinear.

So this means that the center G is the intersection of the line defined by B and A and the line defined by E and C. Similarly, the center H is the intersection of the line defined by A and F and the line defined by C and D.

Given these centers, you can determine the radii of the two circles just from the distance from the center to the tangent point. From there you can use standard methods to draw the arc given its endpoints and the circle it is part of.